# Don't know how to add SSL certificate on Windows Phone 8.1 Portable Class Library

Tags: https, windows-phone-8.1, ssl-certificate, portable-class-library

I tried in many ways to access to a HTTPS server using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient on a portable class library for a windows phone 8.1 App

I need a portable class library and install the ssl certificate on the library whithout action of the user.

Is that possible and if yes, how to do it ?

Comment: Are you talking about a self signed cert?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have my .cer file but don't know how to use it

Comment: in WP8 the only way to add a self signed cert was to host it on a server and point the phones browser to it, which then requires user interaction to add the cert. I doubt 8.1 is any different.

Comment: Seems they may have made a way in WP8.1, Have a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/05/including-self-signed-certificates-with-your-windows-runtime-based-windows-phone-8-1-apps.aspx

Comment: I tried this but could not use it in my unit tests

Answer (score 1):

You can load your certificate from an application file and install it:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/tempRootCa.cer");
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
Certificate rootCert = new Certificate(buffer);
CertificateStore rootStore = CertificateStores.TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities;
rootStore.Add(rootCert);
```